# Sync some projects from Azure Devops to Github or another solution?

Tags: github, azure-devops

I have a big .NET solution with many projects. Everything is on Azure devops, and working well for the team.

Some of these projects are demo project.
I would like a way to publish the code of these demo projects on github, so they will be publicly available.

I'm looking for a way to publish the code of these specific projects to github.

Does anyone have a way to do that efficiently ?

Comment: Are you using Git or TFVC?

Comment: hello @DanielMann, I'm using Git

Comment: Are the projects that you want to publish to GitHub in the same repo as projects you don't want to publish to GitHub, or are they in different repos?

Comment: they are in the same repo

Answer (score 0):

if you are using any previous source control (ex TFS) first Unattache it ,
i presume you are using VS,

- right click the solution then select "Add solution to source control "
- since VS 2015 , GitHub is integrated out of the box , log in to your GitHub account(if you are using an older version just download it as an extension )
- Below are the visuals

[image]

Comment: Hello, 
I'm using Git with Team services (Azure Devops). but I don't want to keep my main source control. What I want is a solution to publish *some* folders to github

Comment: you can't its just one for each at a time , why don't you just make a replica and publish it

Comment: that's a solution, I'll consider it if there is no other way. thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a new folder.
2. Copy to this folder **only** the projects you want to publish on GitHub.
3. Create a new Git repo:

   ```
   git init
   git add .
   git commit -m "first commit"
   ```
4. Create a new repo on GitHub:
   [image]
5. Open cmd and push the new local repo to new GitHub repo.

   ```
   cd path/to/your-new-folder
   git remote add origin https://github.com/{your-user-name}/demo-projcets.git
   git push -u origin master
   ```